# Optimization of a Qt QByteArray conversion

Tags: c++, optimization, converting, qt

I wrote a function to convert a hexadecimal string representation (like 0x00) of some binary data to the data itself.

How can I improve this code?

```
QByteArray restoreData(const QByteArray &data, const QString prepender = "x")
{
    QByteArray restoredData = data;

    return QByteArray::fromHex(restoredData.replace(prepender, ""));
}
```

Comment: Why you need to improve this code? If you really need to do this, try to find way to create QByteArray without copying source data...

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid deep copying of source array, this can be achived with `right` method:

```
QByteArray restoreData(const QByteArray &data, char prepender = 'x')
{
    return QByteArray::fromHex(data.right(data.size() - data.indexOf(prepender) - 1);
}
```